# Meaning behind this formula for complex integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, soft-question

Recall that $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}=\frac 12 \left(\frac {\partial}{\partial  x}+i\frac {\partial}{\partial y}\right)$. From Green's theorem and Cauchy-Riemann formula, we have
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega} f(z)dz = 2i \iint_{\Omega} \frac {\partial f}{\partial \bar z}(x,y) dxdy
$$
for a domain $\Omega$ with reasonably nice boundary. What is the intuition/geometric meaning behind this?

On related note, we also know that a function $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ if $\frac {\partial f}{\partial \bar z}=0$ there. It would be great if someone could give an interesting interpretation of this result .

Comment: That's true. Nevertheless, what I really want to ask is what information does $\frac {\partial}{\partial \bar z}$  encapsulate.

Comment: Well, every smooth function can be written as a function of $z$ and $\bar z$. You're literally differentiating that function with respect to $\bar z$.

Comment: I've rarely seen $\partial/\partial\bar{z}$ used except formally. The expression itself looks suspiciously close to stokes theorem.

Comment: @Ian May I ask how do we decompose $f$ into those  parts you mentioned?

Comment: @Ian To me the $2i$ part is not so suspicious since we know that the Jacobian determinant $\left| \frac {\partial (x,y)}{\partial(z,\bar z)} \right|=-\frac 1{2i}$.

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, you can't decompose as a sum. Try $f(z,\bar z) = |z|^2$. And of course ... this *is* Stokes's Theorem, generalizing Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Really? Are you saying that if $f$ is smooth on an open subset of $\mathbb C$, there is a smooth function $g(z,w)$ defined on an open subset of $\mathbb C^2$ such that $f(z) = g(z,\bar z)$, $\partial f/\partial z = \partial g/\partial z$, and $\partial f/\partial \bar z = \partial g/\partial w$? I know how to show this if $f$ is real-analytic, but how do you prove it if $f$ is just smooth?

Comment: @JackLee: Well, you usually catch me in gruesome errors, but what I had in mind was to first write $f(x+iy)=h(x,y)$ and then set $g(z,w)=h\big(\frac{z+w}2,\frac{z-w}{2i}\big)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: But what does $h(x,y)$ mean when $x$ or $y$ is not real?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't thought this through carefully, so you got me again. Of course, I too, had usually stipulated real analyticity. So, although $\log(x^2+y^2)$ is a smooth function on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, I do not get a well-defined function on $\Bbb C^2-\{0\}$. Back to real analytic. :) Thanks. (P.S. It's comforting to be retired. :))

Comment: @TedShifrin: Too bad -- I was hoping you were right. It would have given an even better way to explain the significance of $\partial f/\partial\bar z$.